# Calculate maximum and minimum elevation for a polygon layer from a DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, dem, elevation

I have a polygon layer and would like to know the min and max elevation within each polygon. My elevation layer is a digital elevation model. I'm not quite sure how to extract that information. 
I am using arcMap 10

Answer (score 3):

[Zonal Statistics As Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) will give you the results you want - inspect the output table for the min and max statistics.

See the identical post [Extract Raster Value into Polygon Attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute).

Comment: I tried zonal statistics but I get a 99999 error. Not really sure what to do. My original polygon layer had overlapping polygons, therefore I had to seperate those that overlapped into different layers. Each layer now has polygons that do not overlap but the error continues to occur. I checked out the answers in the other post with the same question and cannot for some reason extract the values in the alternative method because the function fails everytime I attempt to convert my raster to points. If there is an alternative method I would be willing to try it. Thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: Some things to check: (1) Are the polygons and raster in the same spatial reference? (2) Is the raster cell size much larger than some of the polygons? (3) Look at the usual [spatial analyst 'traps'](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_performing_analysis_in_Spatial_Analyst/005900000014000000/) of no spaces in the directory path or file names, raster file type, extent, etc.

Comment: If all of the above checks seem okay, then maybe try the [ACCRU Tool 7.1.2 Overlap Area Sampling](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/?Page=3063#tools) to deal with each polygon in the original file.