# Calculating population within a polygon from a raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to calculate the population within a set of polygons (representing districts). I have a raster file of population data. Can I assign the population data to the polygons and then sum the population?

Comment: [It appears this question was asked before.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zonal Statistic](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) or [Zonal Statistic as Table](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/). As option use Mean (or whatever you want).