# From raster to vector format?

Tags: data, vectorization, climate, peru

I have files from two sources, one has come from http://www.worldclim.org, contains climate variables such as precipitation and temperature on a world scale, in raster format.

The other has the coordinates of the provinces of Peru. I have prepared the maps separately but I need a new data base of Peru, with their provinces and the **average temperature** of each province, that is in vector format.

How could you generate this data?

Do you know other sources of climatic variables per provinces or districts for countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can extract some points along your polygons (the weather stations?), and the value of the raster at these points.
Then you can compute your average temperature fore each polygon.

Comment: Dear @ppardoz could you give me more details about how to do this, what options could I use? or where can I find more information or examples about this? Please. I am new in ArcGis.

Comment: I do not use ArcGIS, but in QGIS you can create random points inside a polygon. I am sure is quite easy in ArcGIs too. For the second part maybe this can help you http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002t000000.htm

Comment: I dit it with two ways: (1) In QGIS (Sampling Raster Data using Polygons): http://www.qgistutorials.com/es/docs/sampling_raster_data.html. (2) In ArcGIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute. "First, convert the raster to Points using the Raster to Point tool. ...."