# How to calculate the slope of my polygons using DEM

Tags: raster, arcmap, dem, elevation, slope

I downloaded elevation data (DEM) of my study area from NASA and I converted it to slope. How do I calculate the slope of each farm at my study area? I have a shapefile containing the polygons of the farms

Comment: use the zonal stats tool.

Comment: Check out this post:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute