# Roof slope, building footprints,

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, building-heights, rooftop-building

How to extract flat rooftops from NDSM or DSM using ArcMap? I only have polygons of buildings footprints and DSM and DTM data

Comment: Do you have Spatial Analyst extension?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a slope raster
2. then [Extract Raster Value into Polygon Attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute)
3. Select By Attribute polygons with for example low mean slope